# User key binding for packages in Sublime 3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, packages, sidebar

I'm using OS X. At the moment I cannot determine whether it is possible to add user key bindings to packages added to Sublime Text 3. I'm trying to add a user key binding to an action in a package I have installed and cannot make things work. Specifically I'm trying to add a key binding to the command "Edit to Right" in the 'Sidebar Enhancements' package (https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements).

The information on the 'Edit to Right' command can be found on line 48 [here](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/blob/st3/Side%20Bar.sublime-menu).

It states:

```
{
    "caption": "Edit to Right",
    "id": "side-bar-edit-to-right",
    "command": "side_bar_edit_to_right",
    "args": {"paths": []}
},
```

Comment: Please show exactly what you have tried and what the problem is.

Comment: In the user key binding settings I have added:

    { "keys": ["ctrl+super+="], "command": "edit_to_right" }

I have also tried "side_bar_edit_to_right" and "edit_to_right_side_bar" as it was suggested on other questions to add the name of the package. All without success.

Comment: Which command is that? This package (https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) does not seem to have that command. Please [edit] your question and try to be more specific.

Comment: It does, please see line 48 of this file: https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/blob/st3/Side%20Bar.sublime-menu

Currently I have  { "keys": ["ctrl+super='"], "command": "side_bar_edit_to_right" } in my user key bindings, but it only opens a blank tab.

Comment: Again, I can only recommend you to edit your question to include this information (you haven't said what happens when you press the key). Also, posting the same as an issue for the package would probably be the best solution for getting a quick answer.